# Python H2OFrame inconsistent behavior on merge caused by column ordering

Tags: python, python-3.x, h2o

I have the following CSV files that I'm importing into H2OFrames.

CSV 1(a):

```
year,manufacturer,model,salePrice
2010,HONDA,CIVIC,100
2011,TOYOTA,CAMRY,150
2010,HONDA,CIVIC,50
2011,TOYOTA,CAMRY,200
2010,HONDA,CIVIC,150
2011,TOYOTA,CAMRY,250
2012,SUZUKI,SWIFT,500
2012,SUZUKI,SWIFT,600
```

CSV 1(b):

```
manufacturer,model,year,salePrice
HONDA,CIVIC,2010,100
TOYOTA,CAMRY,2011,150
HONDA,CIVIC,2010,50
TOYOTA,CAMRY,2011,200
HONDA,CIVIC,2010,150
TOYOTA,CAMRY,2011,250
SUZUKI,SWIFT,2012,500
SUZUKI,SWIFT,2012,600
```

CSV 2:

```
year,manufacturer,model,bodyType
2010,HONDA,CIVIC,SEDAN
2011,TOYOTA,CAMRY,SEDAN
2012,SUZUKI,SWIFT,HATCHBACK
```

Notice that "1a" and "1b" are exactly the same data with just the columns ordered differently. Now I import all three of them into `H2OFrame` as follows:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
df1a=h2o.import_file('csv1a.csv')
df1b=h2o.import_file('csv1b.csv')
df2=h2o.import_file('csv2.csv')
```

And then I try the following merge operations:

```
merge1=df1a.merge(df2, by_x=['year','manufacturer','model'], by_y=['year','manufacturer','model'])
merge2=df1b.merge(df2, by_x=['year','manufacturer','model'], by_y=['year','manufacturer','model'])
```

The first merge works as expected. But the second one fails with error "Merging columns must be the same type, column salePrice found types Enum and Numeric"

When I checked the logs on the h2o server, I found that the `by_x` column indices sent to the server were exactly the same for both the merges(and ordered - `[0 1 2]`), in spite of the different order in which the `by_x` columns occur in `df1b`. From the server logs..

```
parms={ast=(tmp= py_5_sid_abdb (merge h2o_bug_df1b1.hex h2o_bug_df21.hex False False [0 1 2] [0 1 2] 'auto'))
```

Then I found line #1967 and #3422 in the code of the `h2o.frame` module:
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/jenkins-rel-yates-4/h2o-py/h2o/frame.py#L1967
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/jenkins-rel-yates-4/h2o-py/h2o/frame.py#L3422

For my second merge, the `by_x` column indices should have been `[2 0 1]`, instead the python client sent `[0 1 2]` because of the `list(set(tmp))` statement in line #3422.

So I'm wondering, wouldn't it be better to fail fast and throw an error if the supplied `by_x` or `by_y` column names are not unique, instead of collecting them into a `set` which obviously won't preserve the order?

Also the error message was misleading until I checked the code as the message had a reference to the `salePrice` column which was neither in my `by_x` nor `by_y`.

Comment: thanks for bringing this up, could you create a JIRA ticket (http://jira.h2o.ai ) so the H2O-3 team can consider this update. thanks!

Comment: Reported: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6645